# how to use array_map/array_walk function for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

#### I have the following multidimensional array:

```
array (size=2)
      10 => 
        array (size=7)
          1 => 
            array (size=4)
              0 => string '10view1' (length=7)
              1 => string '10ins1' (length=6)
              2 => string '10edit1' (length=7)
              3 => string '10del1' (length=6)
          2 => 
            array (size=4)
              0 => string '10view2' (length=7)
              1 => string '10ins2' (length=6)
              2 => string '10edit2' (length=7)
              3 => string '10del2' (length=6)
          3 => 
            array (size=4)
              0 => string '10view3' (length=7)
              1 => string '10ins3' (length=6)
              2 => string '10edit3' (length=7)
              3 => string '10del3' (length=6)
      11 => 
        array (size=7)
          1 => 
            array (size=4)
              0 => string '11view1' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins1' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit1' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del1' (length=6)
          2 => 
            array (size=4)
              0 => string '11view2' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins2' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit2' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del2' (length=6)
          3 => 
            array (size=4)
              0 => string '11view3' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins3' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit3' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del3' (length=6)
```

I want to convert it to the array like:

```
1 => array(10 => array( 
              0 => string '10view1' (length=7)
              1 => string '10ins1' (length=6)
              2 => string '10edit1' (length=7)
              3 => string '10del1' (length=6)),
           11 => array(
              0 => string '11view1' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins1' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit1' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del1' (length=6) 
           )
        ),
2 => array(
          10 => array(
             0 => string '10view2' (length=7)
              1 => string '10ins2' (length=6)
              2 => string '10edit2' (length=7)
              3 => string '10del2' (length=6)
          ),
          11 => array(
               0 => string '11view2' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins2' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit2' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del2' (length=6)
          )
      ),
3 => array(
        10 => array(
             0 => string '11view3' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins3' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit3' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del3' (length=6)
          ),
          11 => array(
             0 => string '11view1' (length=7)
              1 => string '11ins1' (length=6)
              2 => string '11edit1' (length=7)
              3 => string '11del1' (length=6) 
          )
    )
```

#### please help me i confuse to solve this problem thanks in advance.

It's quite obvious for me how to implement this using foreach loop, but I wonder if it's possible to do this with PHP array functions like array_map or array_walk. Please use PHP 5.3 for the callback function. Thank you!

Comment: How 'bout this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 0):

Using array map you can achieve like this

```
<?php

function merge_array($n, $m)
{
   $data = array();

   $data[10] = $n;
   $data[11] = $m;

   return $data;

}

$c = array_map("merge_array", $array[10], $array[11]);
print_r($c);
```

Using for loop it is very simple you can achieve like this

```
$count_10 = count($array[10]);

$count_11 = count($array[11]);

$count = ($count_10>$count_11)?$count_10:$count_11;

$data = array();

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{

  if(isset($array[10][$i]))
  {
       $data[$i][] =  $array[10][$i];
  }

  if(isset($array[11][$i]))
  {
       $data[$i][] =  $array[11][$i];
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks you for reply but i used snipped array in this question here actually my array is dynamically so if you are any more idea please tell me.